# How to typeset a number like 10.10.10 with the siunitx package?

Tags: siunitx

I want to list the versions of some python modules I am using. The problem is that the format of the version has two dots, for example 10.10.10 or 1.04.5. When I try \num{10.10.10} I get the error: duplicate-decimal-token.

Is there a way to use the \num command from siunitx to typeset these numbers? Any alternative?

Comment: Well, numbers are supposed to have only one dot (two parts)

Comment: Yes sure. But these particular numbers have two. Any idea?

Comment: What exactly do you expect \num to do with a version number?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I always type numbers with \num{10.10}. I just want to typeset 10.10.10 with the same format that I would use for 10.10

Comment: But does `\num{10.10}` look any different from `10.10`?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I just tried to see if there is any difference between then and with a 400% zoom level I could not see any. But what if I change something later that will result in the number being typeset differently.

Comment: If Alan Munn solves your problem, why don't use just `10.10.10`? It is totally not different at all!

Comment: The most likely change is for \num{10.10) to be written as `$1.01\times 10$`, which is probably not desirable.

Comment: @JouleV I agree that it looks the same but I wanted to learn how to use siunitx in this case.

Comment: @kbr85 `siunitx`'s `\num` command is supposed to change 1000 to 1 000, 1000.0001 to 1 000.000 1 (add spaces). You literally killed this feature in this case. `siunitx` is totally useless here. Don't overuse it.

Comment: @JouleV Thanks for this information. What if I change the font of the document to something that typeset numbers in math mode differently to numbers in text?

Comment: @kbr85 Nothing changes.

Comment: @JouleV Ok. Thanks for the advice and the productive discussion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `parse-numbers` key to `false` for these numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\num[parse-numbers=false]{10.10.10.10}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That did it. I also voted up the answer but not enough privileges so far to change the displayed count. Thanks!!