# Latex tables: **! siunitx error: "duplicate-decimal-token"*

Tags: tables

I have this table:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
  \begin{center}
    \caption{Multirow table.}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{l|S|r}
      \textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
      \hline
      \multirow{2}{*}{2} & 12.03-10.05.2012 & a\\ % <-- Combining 2 rows with arbitrary with (*) and content 12
      & 10.1 & b\\ % <-- Content of first column omitted.
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
```

But I am getting this error message:

**! siunitx error: "duplicate-decimal-token"**

I tried [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487391/how-to-typeset-a-number-like-10-10-10-with-the-siunitx-package) `\num{\num[parse-numbers=false]{12.03-10.05.2012}}` but I keep getting the same error message.

Note that I have this before the start of the document:

```
\usepackage{siunitx} % Required for alignment
\sisetup{
  round-mode          = places, % Rounds numbers
  round-precision     = 2, % to 2 places
}
```

Comment: But how exactly is `12.03.2012` suppose to be read? It is not a decimal number, but more looks like a date to me.

Comment: @daleif indeed, it's a date (I updated the exact date range I want to display, but the error is the same). The date is treated as a decimal number

Comment: Your comment actually solved my issue .... it has been a long time I did not deal with this ... I forgot the basics ... I do not need that S alignment on that column, it's just a date, as you said.... thank you so much for the help

Comment: @daleif, please extend your comment to answer, that question not to be closed "as solved by comment".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are trying to parse a date (in the mm.dd.yyyy format), which of course is not a decimal number, hence the error.

I'm not sure whether `siunitx` might be able to align numbers like this (with parsing switched off, probably not).

Answer (score 2):

In your table declaration, `\begin{tabular}{l|S|r}`, you are asking that *SI-Units eXtended* take care of the second column… In that column, as pointed out by daleif comment, there's the strange number `12.03.2012` that leads to the error “duplicate-decimal-token” (there're two dots in the presumed number)

If you want to write that date with siunitx regardless the decimal separators, you should use `\num[parse-numbers=false]{12.03-10.05.2012}` that's all (but you it won't be able to align it as requested.)
When you use `\num{\num[parse-numbers=false]{12.03-10.05.2012}}` you are asking to format like a number what you previously disabled (kinda infinite loop.)

edit: Finally [daleif has posted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/672322/23418) while I was writing. I don't remove this one as it may be complementary even if it just makes another formulation/phrasing.

Comment: Useful feedback too. Thank you !